# How to Get Key Name from JSON amd form a new json

Tags: java, json

I have a a JSON for Example :-

```
{
   "d-ps":{
   "d-es":{
   "d-e": 
       [
       {
        "dr": "A",
        "dn": "ad",
        "dt": "am",
        "db": "ami",
        "tn": "at",
        "dqr": "A",
        "dc": "GPC-01",
        "bdo": "Ain",
        "tdo": "Adn",
        "de": "St"
        },
        {
        "dr": "A1",
        "dn": "ads",
        "dt": "amd",
        "db": "am",
        "tn": "ats",
        "dqr": "B",
        "dc": "GP-01",
        "bdo": "Ann",
        "tdo": "And",
        "de": "Sat"
        }
        ]
        }
        }
        }
```

I want to get all key name from this JSON which inside d-e array  and then make a new json and include these key in array in json after  d-es in an array as eh:[contains all key which are in d-e array seperated by comma]

Comment: why don't you try it first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the JSOn to XML type and then using xpath extract all Node name from the XML which are inside d-e Node and then made a new XML and include the key in array in xml after d-es Node and then converted it to JSON

Answer (score 0):

Well you could load the json string as a dictionary, then grab the first "d-e" array inside it and iterate trough its keys and add them to an array:

```
jsonDict = {"d-ps":{"d-es":{"d-e":[{"dr":"A","dn":"ad","dt":"am","db":"ami","tn":"at","dqr":"A","dc":"GPC-01","bdo":"Ain","tdo":"Adn","de":"St"},{"dr":"A1","dn":"ads","dt":"amd","db":"am","tn":"ats","dqr":"B","dc":"GP-01","bdo":"Ann","tdo":"And","de":"Sat"}]}}}
deDict = jsonDict['d-ps']['d-es']['d-e'][0]
keysArray = []
for k in de[0].keys():
    keysArray.append(k)
```